# Jquery - how to make checkall is unchecked when one of checkbox uncheck?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

i have a code like this :

```
$("#checkAll").change(function () {
$("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

this code it's work, if i click checkbox `#checkall`, it's check all `checkbox`, if i uncheck `#checkall`, it's uncheck all `checkbox`.

The first problem is if i check `#checkall`, it's check all `checkbox`, but  when i uncheck one of `checkbox` that's `#checkall` still checked, actually it's not checked because one of `checkbox` is unchecked and automatically not checked all.

Second is if i manually check all one by one `checkbox`, the `#checkall` not checked, actually the checked is checked all.

how to solve this?

Comment: In case of unchecked simply uncheck checkall but in case of checked you have to loop through all the checkbox until you found an unselected check box and break it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an event handler to the other checkboxes that simply tests whether all of them are checked or not:

```js
var checkAll = $("#checkAll").click(function () {
  allCBs.prop('checked', this.checked);
});

var allCBs = $("input:checkbox:not(#checkAll)").click(function() {
  checkAll.prop("checked", !allCBs.is(":not(:checked)"));
});
```

```css
label { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label><input type="checkbox" id="checkAll"> Check All</label>
<label><input type="checkbox"> ABC</label>
<label><input type="checkbox"> DEF</label>
<label><input type="checkbox"> GHI</label>
```

Note: I prefer to use the `click` event rather than the `change` event, because some (older IE) browsers don't trigger a `change` until focus leaves the field.

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to monitor all the checkboxes for the change event.
Simple rule is #checkAll should be checked if (and only if) there are no UNCHECKED checkboxes.

something like this:

```
$(document).on("change","input[type=checkbox]",function() {
    $('#checkAll').prop('checked', $('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)' ).length == 0);
});
```

Comment: this would need to go after your posted code, or have some other way to filter out the #checkAll checkbox from acting on this.